# using Spring Cloud Contract Stub Runner and generating stubs from contracts (contracts placed in git) in one place (application)

Tags: java, git, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

is it possible?
I want to create stub server for smoke testing with features:

1. on build it gets contracts of multiple rest applications from git repository, build stubs and push them back to repository as jsons
2. on startup it gets stub jsons from repository and run them

I tried this:

main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableStubRunnerServer
public class SpringCloudStubRunnerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudStubRunnerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.yaml:

```
server:
  port: 8080

stubrunner:
  stubsMode: REMOTE
  repositoryRoot: git://git@github.com:Granomir/spring-cloud-config-stubs.git
  ids:
    - ru.mts.poisk:my-content-adapter:+:stubs:8090
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.mts.poisk</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stub-runner</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-S1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <contractsRepositoryUrl>git://git@github.com:Granomir/spring-cloud-config-stubs.git</contractsRepositoryUrl>
                    <contractDependency>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my-content-adapter</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </contractDependency>
                    <contractsMode>REMOTE</contractsMode>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pushStubsToScm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I 'mvn clean install -DskipTests' for generating stubs than I have following in log:

```
[INFO] Pattern to pick contracts equals [^/tmp/git-contracts-1614681706091-0/META-INF/ru.mts.poisk/my-content-adapter/1.0-S1-SNAPSHOT(/)?.*ru/mts/poisk/spring-cloud-stub-runner/.*$]
[INFO] Ant Pattern to pick files equals [**/ru/mts/poisk/spring-cloud-stub-runner/**/]
```

so my app doesn't generate stubs and has nothing to push back, because I have another directory structure in git